# Eloquent activityfeed - shared polymorphic relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an existing app with a polymorphic relationship setup between the comments and the videos/images table (videos and images can have many comments):

#### videos table

```
- id
- title
```

#### images table

```
- id
- url
```

#### comments table

```
- id
- parent_id (video or image primary key)
- parent_type (video or image)
```

Now my client has requested to add an activityfeed to the app. The feed must pull in all the newly added videos and images ordered by rank with their comments.

I have added an activities table

#### activities table (new)

```
-id
-parent_id (video or image primary key)
-parent_type (video or image)
-rank
-metadata
```

*The metadata column contains some denormalised data to display the feed so i don't have to pull in each and every video or image.*

*Note: above is a simplyfied version of my app. In reality i have more then only video / image types.*

How would i setup Eloquent to fetch all the activities with all the related comments with the least possible queries ? I really really want to prevent to do queries in a foreachloop.

An other database scheme for the activities table is possible.

Comment: What result do you need for this feed?

Comment: What do you mean ? I want to fetch an X amount of activities with their comments

Comment: I mean, do you really need Eloquent result?

Comment: Yeah, i want to use my presenters / repo's / commands etc

Comment: OK, there's no direct way to achieve that, so paste example query you'd like to have and I'll show you how you can do that. By query I mean Eloquent query, not any sql

Comment: In pseudo code i would like to do the following:
`Activities::with('parent.comments');` I understand this will not be possible, but maybe you could help me find another way ? The point is i want some sort of eager/lazy load the comments to keep it performent

Comment: @PinkFloyd if you didn't solve the problem yet, have a look at [polymorphic relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations); if you used it properly you can fetch the comments this way `Activities::with('parent.comments')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
class Activity extends Eloquent {

    function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo($this->getParentEloquentClass(), 'parent_id');
    }

    private function getParentEloquentClass() {
        switch ($this->parent_type) {
            case 'video':
                return 'Video'; // or your video model class name
            case 'image':
                return 'Image'; // or your image model class name
            ....
        }
    }
}

class Video extends Eloquent {
    function activities() {
        return $this->hasMany('Activity', 'activity_id');
    }
}
```

Then you may be able to query latest activities with comments like you mentioned:

```
Activity::with('parent.comments');
```

I'm not sure if this will work, but it worth to give it a try.

Comment: I tried this, but sadly the belongsto relationship is only defined once. So if the first row has a parent_type of Video, all consecutive rows will have a relationship with the Video table